# issue with converting date and time to millisecond format in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, date, datetime, time

I am working on an angularjs web application which uses REST layer to communicate with the backend. I have to display the date and time of a job but I receive it in milliseconds format. How do I convert the value to display the date and time on the UI.

```
1479982860000     // input
11/24/16          //output date
10:21 AM          //output time
```

Both have to be stored in DataModel.date and DataModel.time.

Also the user enters a date and a time which I have to combine and send it in the same milliseconds format to the REST layer. How do I do that?

```
<input type="time" id="exampleInput1" ng-model="DataModel.time"
                                                placeholder="HH:mm:ss" required/>

<input type="date" id="exampleInput2" ng-model="DataModel.date"
                                                placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required/>
```

I have to combine the two and send it as Datamodel.date in the controller. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/)

Add configuration in your JS file

```
/*Configuration to change the date format*/
angular.module('myapp')
    .config(function($mdDateLocaleProvider) {
        $mdDateLocaleProvider.formatDate = function(date) {
            return date ? moment(date).format('DD/MM/YYYY') : '';
     };

        $mdDateLocaleProvider.parseDate = function(dateString) {
            var m = moment(dateString, 'DD/MM/YYYY', true);
            return m.isValid() ? m.toDate() : new Date(NaN);
        };
    })
```

Change the format which ever way you want

```
var newFormatDate =moment(oldFormatDate).format();
```

**EDITS**

If you want to set specific timezone,

```
moment().tz("America/Los_Angeles");
```

[**MOMENT.JS DOCS**](http://momentjs.com/timezone/docs/)

Also look at [**timezone identifier**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones)

Comment: I have a doubt. i am using moment.js now

Comment: I need to display the date and  time in american time zone. So for date I did this

Comment: DataModel.date=moment(new Date(milliseconds)).tz("Time Zone");

Comment: But how do I do it for time? I tried to do it the same way for time but does not work

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example to achieve what you need,

use

**`(new Date($scope.milli_seconds))` to get the full date.**

**`(new Date($scope.milli_seconds)).toDateString() to get the date from it`**

**`(new Date($scope.milli_seconds)).toTimeString()` to get the time from it**

**`(new Date($scope.milli_seconds)).getTime()` to convert bact to milliseconds**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

  "milliseconds" : {{milli_seconds}} <br>
"full_date" : {{full_date}} <br>
"date" : {{date}} <br>
"time" : {{time}} <br>
"millisecondsreverse" : {{milli_seconds_reverse}} <br>
<br><br>                                               
<input type="time" id="exampleInput1" ng-model="DataModel.time"
                                                placeholder="HH:mm:ss" required/>

<input type="date" id="exampleInput2" ng-model="DataModel.date"
                                                placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required/>
                                                
<input type="submit" ng-click="submit_values()" value="getmilliseconds"/> <br>                                               
<span ng-if="milli">Your milliseconds: {{milli}}</span>


</div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.DataModel = {}
    $scope.milli_seconds = 1479982860000;
    $scope.full_date = (new Date($scope.milli_seconds))
    $scope.date = $scope.full_date.toDateString()
    $scope.time = $scope.full_date.toTimeString()
    $scope.milli_seconds_reverse = $scope.full_date.getTime();
    
    $scope.submit_values = function()
    {
    date = new Date($scope.DataModel.time).toTimeString()
    time = new Date($scope.DataModel.date).toDateString()
    date_time = (new Date($scope.DataModel.date).toDateString())+" "+ (new Date($scope.DataModel.time).toTimeString())
    alert(new Date(date_time).getTime());
    $scope.milli = new Date(date_time).getTime();
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Please run the above snippet**

You can just convert it into different formats you like, using the filters.

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ym6x1z13/2/)

Comment: And how do I convert the date and time input to millisec

Comment: just use,`getTime();` method. `$scope.full_date.getTime();`. updated my answer. please check

Comment: How do I convert the date and time inputs to milliseconds

Comment: please check the answer now

Comment: how do you propose to combine the date and time inputs from the user to get the full_date

Comment: how will your date and time look like?

Comment: I have provided the code snippet above for the date and time inputs. They are both user inputs; input type date and input type time

Comment: ok so, I should take date and time from that inouts and need to convert to milliseconds right?

Comment: right Sravan, That is what I want. I have searched for it but only complicated solutions found

Comment: you can accept and vote my answer, if you find it useful. :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date), you can convert the value in your controller.

```
$scope.date = new Date($scope.DataModel.time);
$scope.date= $filter('date')(new Date($scope.DataModel.time), 'yyyy-mm-dd');
```

and the view:

```
<input type="date" id="exampleInput2" ng-model="date" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" required/>
```

Don't forget to add $filter in your dependencies:

```
app.controller('YourController', ['$scope','$filter', function($scope, $filter) {

}]);
```

Answer (score 0):

[This may work for your issue]

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date